# Force users to accept answers by restricting them from asking if they don't

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

Can we have a limit on users posting questions and then not accepting answers for those? As this becomes challenging for the person answering and people who face similar issues simply ignore answers as that are not accepted.

I have an idea where a particular user will have a cap up to which they can ask questions. For the sake of it, let’s say, 5. But when they are going to ask a sixth question, they will be prompted to revisit their old questions and accept an answer that worked for them.

I know there are many questions that remain unanswered for very long period. For that, let’s add a pass button where the user can just get pass the question, but let’s add a good delay to it, say, 6 hours.

What effect will this have overall?

1. It will reward the user who painstakingly is answering the question.
2. It will increase people's interest in getting a guaranteed reward
3. It will limit traffic from users who break problem statements into smaller chunks to get them answered.
4. It will help the person asking questions to take responsibility instead of just benefitting from the received answer.

I know the numbers for time intervals and the question cap will be tough to decide, but this will be quite helpful overall in the community to propagate positive responses.

Comment: Part of posting a good feature request is writing a good title.

Comment: What if somebody accepts wrong answers just for overcoming the limit.

Comment: I'm not seeing why this is a problem that needs to be solved, you aren't entitled to having your answer accepted. Not to mention that this particular solution will just encourage people to accept answers that don't actually work, which is worse than accepting nothing.

Comment: If you treat the answer that is accepted as the solution as a higher importance than the votes, you are using the site wrong. Evaluate the answers by yourself, work out which is best for you, and then upvote the one(s) that helped you. Acceptance is honestly barely of any importance.

Comment: I'm dating myself, but I'm an "old-timer" on this site, have been here more than 13 years, and can tell you that this was a problem years ago, but it was the opposite problem. Back then, the member's answer acceptance rate was part of their profile, and this caused no small measure of unneeded animosity, bullying and drama. I hope and pray that your suggestion is not implemented, and that instead people post answers for the pleasure of creating and sharing useful information.

Comment: And yes, as @ThomA implied, your meta question title could use some improvement. Just like on the main site, it should offer a helpful fair summary of your meta topic.

Comment: Please pick just one primary tag. This is either a feature request or a discussion. Since you originally chose feature request, I removed the discussion tag for you. If you _do_ intend for this to be a discussion, let me know in a reply and I'll be happy to dupe-hammer the post against the target Nick found.

Comment: "Can we have a limit on user posting questions and then not accepting answers for those." - Accepting an answer has never been required.  Some questions never receive a question that can or should be accepted.  Why should user's who asked the question be punished for the author's of low quality answers?  I also remember the amount of answers you accepted was part of your profile, and the absolute toxic behavior, that surfaced due to that statistic.

Comment: And please don't ask users to accept an answer using comments.

Comment: "Can we have a limit on user posting questions and then not accepting answers for those." - no, because **there is nothing inherently wrong with doing that**. Question acceptance is really a misfeature; the purpose of questions here **is not** to get OP's problem resolved, but to **provide framing for answers** so that the question and answers contribute to a searchable reference library. "It will help the person asking questions to take responsibility instead of just benefitting from the received answer." - we already teach this by **upholding question standards and closing bad questions**.

Comment: "It will limit traffic from users who break problem statements into smaller chunks to get them answered." - not only is this not a problem in itself, it's **explicitly desirable** that problems are broken down into logical steps. It's just that, for each step, the new question is subject to the same standards of clarity, focus, research and not-being-a-duplicate.

Comment: Got the issue with the whole idea. And fair enough. Thanks for entertaining this whimsical request and post going through everyone's perspective I too will support in favor of not doing so.... And thank everyone for enlightening me on the fact of the matter.

Comment: That was the quickest no possible. "Force..." -> no. Try again. Complete do-over written from a perspective of being a visitor, not a gatekeeper.

Comment: @Gimby To be fair, that title was added by another user (since the original one was...less than descriptive).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We used to have something quite similar called acceptance rate. It was [retired as a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) because it was used to bully and harass people into accepting questions that they really didn't think solved their problem or helped them at all.

The other problem we'll get is users accepting answers that don't work at all just so they can ask another question.

In the end you can only have a single accept per answer but you can have an infinite number of upvotes so upvotes are far more valuable than that single accept. Write your answer so that it helps everyone and just wait for those upvotes to happen for you.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at some numbers to check how huge this problem is. I have [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1815878) that sums for an asker for each not closed question:

- asked questions without an accepted answer
- total asked questions
- number of answers for those not yet accepted question
- total view count
- accept rate.

More than 50,000 users come-up but the tail-end very quickly drops to about 16 questions per user.

The top 5 on that list are good for 11,000,000 views. That is revenue for Stack Overflow, so they can keep the lights on and the CEO employed.

If we would put a cap on how many good questions you can ask due to a requirement on accepting prior questions, we could have risked that those view generating questions weren't asked here but on 4Chan.

Accepting is a privilege. It is given to the OP because we trust them to select the answer that helped them the most. That is a decision only they can make. If no answer qualifies for that honor then so be it. OPs shouldn't be pressured to mislead 11,000,000 visitors so they can ask another great question.

Comment: True that it will be very tough and this can take toll on the user asking the question also at the same time is disastrous as subpar answer might get accepted

Comment: It's microscopic because it is not a problem to begin with :) It is... a statistic.